# Symfony Messenger: Send logged messenger errors per email (via swift_mailer)?

Tags: email, symfony4, messenger, monolog

I've configured monolog to send errors via email as described in the symfony docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/logging/monolog_email.html

Works well with all errors happing during a request, as well as console command errors.
But it does not send emails for errors which occurred during the handling of a messenger message.

Errors are shown when running the consumer `bin/console messenger:consume async -vv` and they also show up in prod.log like this:
`[2020-01-10 12:52:38] messenger.CRITICAL: Error thrown while handling message...`

Thanks for any hints on how to set up monolog to get messenger errors emailed too.

Comment: Same issue !! Any idea, did you find any solution ?

Comment: @famas23 no, not really. I'm using supervisord with superlance plugin to keep the consumer command running, and if it crashes I get at least notified by email and can have a look at the symfony logfile
see: https://serverfault.com/questions/241721/get-notification-from-supervisord-when-a-job-exits

Comment: I found the solution, gonna posted tonight, it's about monolog buffer resseting :) just one question about supervisor do we need to add this part of configuration if we are in production (not in docker context)
```[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:apache2]
command=/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: these are two sepate configsettings, I don't use any of them

`[supervisord] 
nodaemon=true`
- run supervisor in foreground, thats usally not what you want on production

`[program:apache2] 
command=/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND`
- run and restart apache, the -DFOREGROUND flag should not be used on production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact monolog `swift_mailer` type use [SwiftMailerHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/Handler/SwiftMailerHandler.php) 
wish also implements reset interface and use memory spool by default wish keep all emails in buffer until it is destructed, so till  the end of request :

- onKernelTerminate
- onCliTerminate
- OR till reset method is called, which means that for messenger worker no emails will be send ever because ther's no instant flush - all of them will be kept in in-memory buffer, and probably lost if the process will be killed.

To solve this, you can just disable the default spool `memory` setting for swiftmailer.
Another solution is to flush your emails after `WorkerMessageFailedEvent`  event gets fired, you can implement an event subscriber to do it for this.

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Event\WorkerMessageFailedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Event\WorkerMessageHandledEvent;
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\ResetInterface;

/**
 * Class ServiceResetterSubscriber.
 */
class ServiceResetterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

     protected ResetInterface $servicesResetter;
     public function __construct(ResetInterface $servicesResetter)
     {
         $this->servicesResetter = $servicesResetter;
     }
     public function resetServices(): void
     {
         $this->servicesResetter->reset();
     }
     public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
     {
         return [
             WorkerMessageFailedEvent::class => ['resetServices', 10],
         ];
     }

 }
```

Register your service with the right argument:

```
App\EventSubscriber\ServiceResetterSubscriber:
    arguments: ['@services_resetter']
```

By the way without this (and without buffer limit) your app will leak and no emails will be sent ever.

**Another trick:**
*Make sure that your message implements `\JsonSerializable` to get the message content in your logs, because messenger uses his monolog directly and its context serializer wish use json_encode for seriliazation.
That's why we need to customize their JSON representation when encoded is done with json_encode.*